# Как передать объект simpleXml в метод?

Tags: php, xml

Имеется код для парсинга XML файла в объект. Но проблема в том, что при попытке передать объект simpleXml в метод мне ругается таким образом **Only variables should be passed by reference**. Пример кода чуть ниже привожу. Ругается именно на строку с вызовом parseTournaments

**P.S. Забыл уточнить - $this->data и есть наш корневой объект, в метод передается вложенный объект $country**

```
public function parseStruct()
    {
        $root = new Root();
        foreach($this->data->sport as $sport) {
            $root->createSport($sport['name'], $sport['id']);
            foreach($sport->country as $country) {
                $root->createCountry($country['name'], $sport['id'], $country['id']);
                $sport_obj = end($root->getSports());
                $country_obj = end($root->getCountries());
                $this->parseTournaments($sport_obj, $country_obj, $country);
            }
        }
        return $root;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Назначьте результат взрыва переменной и передайте эту переменную в `end`

```
$tmp1 =$root->getSports();
$tmp2 = $root->getCountries();

sport_obj = end($tmp1);
$country_obj = end($tmp2);
```

End работает ссылкой, а в текущем примере он не может массив преобразовать в ссылку